# lavaan - fixing standardized parameter values

Tags: r, r-lavaan

In lavaan if we would want to test if a certain parameter is greater than 0.6 we would use:

```
fit.model.free <- '
F1 =~ V1 + V2 +V3
F1 ~~ F1
' %>% cfa(data)

fit.model.fix <- '
F1 =~ 0.6*V1 + V2 +V3
F1 ~~ F1
' %>% cfa(data)

anova(fit.model.free, fit.model.fix)
```

But what if I'm actually interested to see if the ***standardized*** parameter is greater than 0.6? What code should I use to specify such a model?

Comment: try fixing the variance at 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To standardize the loading, you need both the observed variable and the common factor to be standardized. You can do this with options on the cfa() call:

std.ov=T  # standardizes observed variables
std.lv=T  # standardizes the common factors

Then the .60 in your second model will be a standardized loading.